# EntityFramework failing to connect when downloaded by ClickOnce (vs2010) on Windows 8

Tags: entity-framework, wcf, clickonce

A newbie question.

Having completed an application using WCF and EntityFramework (each in different projects), I am trying to deploy it with ClickOnce.  In visual studio 2010, the application was published to a directory on my laptop. The files were then copied to a tablet pc running windows 8.

When the program is run, I get a Connection Error with a target machine actively refusing it 127.0.0.1:24324.

This application runs well on my laptop and nowhere is 127.0.0.1 used (by me). The working program (on my laptop) has a class that determines the network I am on and then adjusts the connection string to the appropriate address of the network server.

What happened? And how do I fix it?

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: The Web.config file for my working machine, the laptop, is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="LibraryConnection" 
     connectionString="server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;port=xxxx;user id=id;password=mypassword;database=mydatabase"
     providerName="Npgsql" />
</connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
 </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
   <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
   </system.serviceModel>

<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

The working app.config from the client project is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
   <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
 </startup>

<system.serviceModel>
 <bindings>
   <basicHttpBinding>
     <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_INovaDataService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="6553600" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="6553600" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

 <client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:24324/DataService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_INovaDataService" contract="DataService.INovaDataService" name="BasicHttpBinding_INovaDataService"/>
</client>

<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>

 </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: First thing , 127.0.0.1 means IP address of local machine(localhost),so meaning of it means your builded url will be localhost:24324 is similiar as 127.0.0.1:1234  Second thing, your WCF application requires hosting environment, so please let us know where did you hosted your application in new machine? or it is running in Visual studio?

Comment: @AshokRathod Umm...Please excuse my ignorance. On my laptop I am simply running it as a WPF application. Runs well. On the table pc, I have nothing special installed other then the .net framework. (Visual Studio is not on the tablet pc) and I am not using (that I know of) any web services.

Comment: @AshokRathod In the new machine, I simply ran setup.exe and let it install itself.

Comment: so how you are going to access your wcf service?

Comment: somehow you are using wcf service right?

Comment: @AshokRathod The visual studio solution is divided into three projects: an entityframework project,  a WCF project, and a WPF Client project. The WPF client project calls the WCF project which, inturn, calls the entityframework. The entityframework then connects to the network server. It all works well on my laptop.

Comment: @AshokRathod I added the web.config from the WCF project and the app.config from the client to the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62598/discussion-between-alan-wayne-and-ashok-rathod).